# conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1 on andengine live wallpaper

Tags: android, andengine, dalvik

I built a parallax live wallpaper with **andEngine**. I exported the `.apk` without any problems. I copied the project, updated the package and app name and everything needed to republish as a new `.apk`. The app tests fine on my tablet. But when I try to export it, it throws:

```
conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1
```

After hunting forums, here are the ways I've tried to fix the problem to no avail.

- Update proGuard to it's latest version.
- Updating the SDK to the latest version.
- Removing project from workspace, changing it's directory and re-importing.
- Removing everything but Android 'version#' in Java Build Path->libraries
- Removing everything in Java Build Path->libraries and ran fix project properties.
- Removing and regenerating the `R.txt` file in bin.
- Clearing the `.jar` file from the libs directory.
- Changing my `.apk` and keystore directory.
- Cleaning the project after all of the above.
- Refreshing the project after all of the above.
- Running fix project properties after all of the above.

Occasionally the exporter won't throw the error. But it doesn't build the `.apk`, it just builds the keystore and closes.

I'm pretty stumped. If anyone has insight it would be invaluable.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the latest Android SDK (API 17). I tried all of the above without success. Then I reverted all changes and this is what works for me now:

1. Clean project
2. Turn off Eclipce
3. Clean temp directory (on Windows, %TEMP%)
4. Turn on Eclipse, export (sometimes I clean the project once more)

What usually happens is that the temp directory will contain some files from previous export that cause problems and you can't delete them while they are used. Hence the "Turn off eclipse" step.

Note that some files will stay in temp and you won't be able to remove them - don't worry about it, some other programs use them.